# Read a file separated by tab and put the words in an ArrayList

Tags: java, file-io, tabs

I am doing a self learning exercise to help me understand more about Java, but I am stuck at this question. I have the following txt file:

```
Name  Hobby 
Susy  eat fish 
Anna  gardening
Billy bowling with friends
```

Note: **name and hobby are separated by tab**

What is the best way to read all the line and put it in arraylist(name,hobby). The tricky part is that

```
eat fish or bowling with friends
```

has white spaces and it must be put under one array and obviously I cannot hardcode it. Here is my current code:

```
 public void openFile(){
            try{
                FileInputStream fstream = new    FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
          // use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
          ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();
          String lineJustFetched;
          while ((lineJustFetched = br.readLine()) != null)   {
          String[] tokens = lineJustFetched.split(" \t");
```

I got an error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   -1

I suspect counting the index is not very useful on a tab.
Any idea?

Comment: Make sure no new/empty line is present at the end of the file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alright, you need to do the recipe shown below:

1. Create a `BufferedReader`
2. Create an `ArrayList<String>`
3. Start reading data into a `String` variable named `lineJustFetched`.
4. Split the `String` by calling `lineJustFetched.split("\t");`
5. Iterate over the `String[]` produced. Check if the token you want to enter into the `ArrayList` is not `""`
6. If not, add the word to the `ArrayList`

You specify that you need to split based on `\t` values so white spaces won't be an issue.

**SSCCE**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordsInArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/little/Downloads/test"));
            ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
            String lineJustFetched = null;
            String[] wordsArray;

            while(true){
                lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
                if(lineJustFetched == null){  
                    break; 
                }else{
                    wordsArray = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
                    for(String each : wordsArray){
                        if(!"".equals(each)){
                            words.add(each);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for(String each : words){
                System.out.println(each);
            }

            buf.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
John
likes to play tennis
Sherlock
likes to solve crime
```

Comment: hi ive edit my source code as you instructed.. is it correct?

Comment: @user2891092 I posted an SSCCE for you.

Comment: but it put everything into one arraylist. is it possible to separate them into two arraylist (ex. john is put into names and likes to play tennis is put to hobby)?

Comment: Yes. In that case every odd-numbered word will go into names and every even-numbered word will go into hobby. Get what I am saying ? =)

Comment: Isn't there a Java library that does this common task? E.g., Python has [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you separated Name and Hobby column with tab `\t`, you should do something like this (and don't forget to close scan at end):

```
public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("D://a.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(scan.hasNext()){
        String curLine = scan.nextLine();
        String[] splitted = curLine.split("\t");
        String name = splitted[0].trim();
        String hobby = splitted[1].trim();
        if(!"Name".equals(name)){
            names.add(name);
        }
        if(!"Hobby".equals(hobby)){
            hobbies.add(hobby);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(names);
    System.out.println(hobbies);
    scan.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For others still stumbling upon this.

Using `Stream` API (Java 8), this can be done as

This shows

- Filter method to filter the first header element from the list
- map method to map each element in stream to another element for new stream.

```java
package com.bhavya.stackoverflow.examples.q19575308;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

/**
 * Java 8 Stream API to handle file reading.
 *
 * @author bhavya.work
 */
public class StreamTests {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      InputStream fileInputStream;
      BufferedReader bufferedReader;
      final String filepathInSamePackage = "textfile.txt";
      //filter predicate
      Predicate<String> filterFirstLine =
          line -> !(
              "Name".equals(line.split("\t", -1)[0])
                  && "Hobby".equals(line.split("\t", -1)[1])
          );

      //Implementation 1 returns Arrays as asked.

      System.out.println("==ArrayList==");
      fileInputStream = StreamTests.class.getResourceAsStream(filepathInSamePackage);
      bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));

      bufferedReader
          .lines()
          .filter(filterFirstLine)
          .map(s -> {
            String[] splitStrings = s.split("\t", -1);
            return Arrays.asList(splitStrings);
          }).forEach(System.out::println);

      //Implementation 2 returns HashMap as another example

      fileInputStream = StreamTests.class.getResourceAsStream(filepathInSamePackage);    
      bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
      System.out.println("\n==HashMap==");

      bufferedReader
          .lines()
          .filter(filterFirstLine)
          .map(s -> {
            String[] splitStrings = s.split("\t", -1);
            HashMap<String, String> stringStringMap = new HashMap<>();
            stringStringMap.put(splitStrings[0], splitStrings[1]);
            return stringStringMap;
          }).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And the output

```
==ArrayList==
[Susy, eat fish]
[Anna, gardening]
[Billy, bowling with friends]

==HashMap==
{Susy=eat fish}
{Anna=gardening}
{Billy=bowling with friends}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [commons-lang library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/index.html). Among many other useful things you can split a string using a delimiter:

```
String x="Billy bowling with friends";

String y[]=StringUtils.split(x, '\t');
```

Assuming there is a tab between `Billy` and `bowling`,

- y[0] contains "Billy"
- y[1](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/index.html) contains "bowling with friends"

Answer (score 0):

For future references when you parse out tab there is a delimiter such as "\t" for tab.
Use that instead of .split("   ")

Also, when your error is thrown because it means no character is found, hence the -1, so when you try to store it in an Array... -1 is not valid. (throw in a check for that)

You can step throw your program F10 or F11..or some other key depending on your IDE

Just some tips